# How to fix "photos can not be regenerated" bug in Piwigo?

Tags: imagick

This question also posted on GitHub at https://github.com/Piwigo/Piwigo/issues/1003.

Getting error `# photos can not be regenerated` in Batch -> Generate Multiple Batch Size Images. Image sizes not being generated on upload.

Piwigo appears to be looking in the wrong directory for uploaded image files.

From the php_errors.log file:

```
[13-Apr-2019 18:48:48 America/New_York] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'unable to open image `././upload/2019/04/13/20190413172232-f087ab9d.jpg': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2702' in ...\piwigo\admin\include\image.class.php:415
Stack trace:
#0 ...\piwigo\admin\include\image.class.php(415): Imagick->__construct('././upload/2...')
#1 ...\piwigo\admin\include\image.class.php(87): image_imagick->__construct('././upload/2...')
#2 ...\piwigo\i.php(524): pwg_image->__construct('././upload/2...')
#3 {main}
  thrown in ...\piwigo\admin\include\image.class.php on line 415
```

Installed on Windows 10 x64 with Apache 2.4 and PHP 5.6.2.